# PL/SQL: IF ELSE statement and working with an invalid string from user input

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I am taking in user input from a database.  When the user enters an invalid name that is not in the database I am trying to get an error message saying that the input is not in the database.  I cant figure out what belongs after the v_employee_name.  Any help would be great. Thanks!!

```
ACCEPT p_1 PROMPT 'Please enter the employee Name'

DECLARE
v_employee_name    VARCHAR2(40) :='&p_1';
(Declared Cursors)

BEGIN
   if v_employee_name (???????)  then
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The employee is not in the database' || UPPER(v_employee_name));
   else  
     ...........
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot expect the database to validate the user's input as if by magic.  Because databases aren't magic.  So what you need to do is *write a query*.  I know, shocking.

```
ACCEPT p_1 PROMPT 'Please enter the employee Name'

DECLARE
  v_employee_id   employees.emp_id%type;
(Declared Cursors)

BEGIN

  begin
     select emp_id into v_employee_id
     from employees
     where employee_name = upper('&p_1');
     -- do something
     ....
  exception
     when no_data_found  then
         raise_application_error(-20000, 'The employee is not in the database' || UPPER(v_employee_name));
   end;  
   ....
```

Incidentally, if you're going to capitalize the name in the output you should probably capitalize when doing the validation, as case matters when testing for equality.